# Reprojecting vector datasets in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, vector

I want to change one Personal Geodatabase projection to another.

Can you give me instructions to re-project vector data?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options that may help you:

*note* make sure Define Projection (Data Management) was not used to "change projection" from the source projection

Create a new feature dataset within a personal GDB and import your vector data

1. Right click on a folder in Catalog and select new > personal
   geodatabase
2. Right click on the newly created personal geodatabase select new >
   feature dataset
3. From the window, name your PGDB and import or select the coordinate
   system you need.
4. Right click on your newly created feature dataset and select import > Feature Class (multiple)

Once your feature classes are imported into your new feature dataset, they will automatically have the projection system you defined earlier.

To project feature classes with an existing projection system to a different projection system:

1. From ArcToolbox, select Data Management > Projections and
   Transformations > Feature > Batch Project
2. In the interactive window, import or choose your projection system
3. Define output

If you have tried these already, I may have a few more ideas for you.